# Using Drools to perform an Action based on Events

Tags: events, drools

I wanted to use drools for one of our projects - Online Buying and Selling.

Events are like Buying a book, Buying a pen, Buying a kindle.
These events are stored in a database.

Now, based on the events happened before, I want to decide the consequence.

Like say if a person had the following sequence,

```
1. Buy a book at a price.
2. Sell the same book at a higher price.
```

Then

```
Do something based on that.
```

If someone has done this,

```
1. Buy a kindle.
2. Purchase a book in Science Section of books.
```

Then

```
show him the relevant content in the UI.
```

I have all the listed things as Events in the database.
Now I have written an interface for the Actions to be done and I have also done the interface to pass a Customer when an event happens.

Now what would give me the best performance to process the events and make a decision based on the sequence of events. I cannot store all the events in memory for sure as I have a whole lot of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different aspects to consider:

- For recommending additional items to customers, there are [Recommendation Engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469281/recommendation-engine). You may want to use one of those, if most/all of Your use-cases are recommendations.
- Storing "all the events in memory" is not neccessarily required. In fact, Drools removes events that are no longer relevant to the rule base. The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-fusion-docs/html/ch02.html#d0e184) says

> *"Events may be automatically expired after some time in the working memory. Typically this happens when, based on the existing rules in the knowledge base, the event can no longer match and activate any rules. Although, it is possible to explicitly define when an event should expire."*

- To allow early removal of events, I would use Drools to generate aggregated data like "likes science topics", "owns a e-book reader", etc. Those can be inferred from the events but consume less memory.